# Find the duplicate element from an integer

Tags: c++, c

Last week I attended interview. They asked a question for finding a duplicate element in integer value.I know program using array but they asked to me without array. Please help me for finding duplicate element in integer without array.

Question:

**Find the duplicate element from an integer display the element without the duplicate number. Like I/P:43456 O/P:4356. Condition: no array should be used**

Coding:

```
void printRepeating(int arr[], int size) {
    int i;
    printf("The repeating elements are: \n");
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (arr[abs(arr[i])] >= 0)
            arr[abs(arr[i])] = -arr[abs(arr[i])]; elseprintf(" %d ", abs(arr[i]));
    }
}
int main() {
    int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 6, 6 };
    int arr_size = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]);
    printRepeating(arr, arr_size);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: If you cannot solve this yourself, then maybe you aren't meant for this particular job.

Comment: Seriously I don't known this . I want to know this program. That only I ask this.

Comment: Loop through your input. At each integer iterate towards the beginning of the input until you find the same integer (don't print it in that case), or you reach the beginning (do print the integer).

Comment: Most straightforward way (since there are only 10 distinct digits) is to use a bitmask (a short will do) instead of an array. Or, there's a way to do this with recursion, but it's not very efficient.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick: Arguably, a bitmask can be seen as an array of bits (that's how you're using them anyway).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I actually understood the question to mean that an integer, not an array of integers, should be given as input:

> They asked a question for finding a duplicate element in integer value.

Here is a solution that treats this problem. In my original solution the main function was recursive. This function seemed to work, but I had misunderstood that the problem requires that the duplicate digits be taken from the lower order digits first. My recursive solution removed the higher order digits first. This meant that for the sample input provided, `43456` evaluated to `3456` instead of the desired `4356`.

I have redesigned the `remove_dups()` function to satisfy this requirement. It is no longer recursive. The function builds a new number by consuming the input number, taking the highest order digit and combining it with the highest order digit of remaining digits, after removing duplicates.

There are three helper functions used. The `remove_digits()` function is used to remove all occurrences of a digit from a number. The `get_place()` and `remove_place()` functions are used to get a digit in a given place, where a place is represented by 1, 10, 100,..., and to remove a digit from a given place, respectively.

Here is an example of how the `get_place()` function works:

```
get_place(1234, 100) --> (1234 % (10 * 100) - 1234 % 100) / 100
                     --> (1234 % 1000 - 1234 % 100) / 100
                     --> (234 - 34) / 100
                     --> 200 / 100
                     --> 2
```

And an example of how the `remove_place()` function works:

```
remove_place(1234, 100) --> (1234 / (10 * 100)) * 100 + 1234 % 100
                        --> (1234 / 1000) * 100 + 34
                        --> 1 * 100 + 34
                        --> 100 + 34
                        --> 134
```

## Update

The code that I originally posted did not handle negative numbers. This is because when I initially tested with negative numbers, the results were incorrect. In this broken version I used `long` values in the functions, except for the `plc` parameters, which were `unsigned long`. I wrongly assumed that this problem had to do with the modulus operator, and just changed everything to `unsigned`. It seemed that it would be simple enough to convert a desired negative number to a positive one, and then multiply the result by -1. Here are the function prototypes for the original, broken code:

```
long get_place(long num, unsigned long plc);
long remove_place(long num, unsigned long plc);
long remove_digits(long num, long d);
long remove_dups(long num);
```

But further consideration has revealed that the original problem was that an `unsigned long` value can not be converted to a `long` value, since there are `unsigned long` values that are not representable as `long` values. This was leading to some garbage results in the `get_place()` and `remove_place()` functions. Changing everything to `unsigned long` resolved this problem, at the cost of excluding negative input values. But, with a better understanding of the problem, I changed all of the function parameters and return values to type `long`. This resolves the issue, and allows negative input values to be processed correctly.

Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

long get_place(long num, long plc);
long remove_place(long num, long plc);
long remove_digits(long num, long d);
long remove_dups(long num);

int main(void)
{
    long number;

    printf("Enter a number (q to quit): ");
    while (scanf("%ld", &number) == 1) {
        printf("%ld\n", remove_dups(number));
        printf("Enter a number (q to quit): ");
    }

    return 0;
}

/* return digit at plc = 1, 10, 100, ... */
long get_place(long num, long plc)
{
    return (num % ( 10 * plc) - num % plc) / plc;
}

/* remove digit at plc = 1, 10, 100, ..., and return result */
long remove_place(long num, long plc)
{
    return (num / (10 * plc)) * plc + num % plc;
}

/* remove all occurrences of d in num and return result */
long remove_digits(long num, long d)
{
    long place = 1;
    while (num / place) {
        if (get_place(num, place) == d)
            num = remove_place(num, place);
        else
            place *= 10;
    }

    return num;
}

long remove_dups(long num)
{
    long result, next_digit;
    long last_place = 1;

    result = 0;
    while (num) {
        for(last_place = 1; (num / (10 * last_place)); last_place *= 10)
            continue;

        next_digit = get_place(num, last_place);
        result = result * 10 + next_digit;
        num = remove_digits((num % last_place), next_digit);
    }
    return result;
}
```

Here is some sample output:

```
Enter a number (q to quit): -43456
-4356
Enter a number (q to quit): 43456
4356
Enter a number (q to quit): -12321
-123
Enter a number (q to quit): 299792458
297458
Enter a number (q to quit): 0
0
Enter a number (q to quit): 1
1
Enter a number (q to quit): -1
-1
Enter a number (q to quit): q
```

Comment: @Meena-- I just added an example of how the recursive function evaluates to an answer.

Comment: @David-- this program clearly help to find a duplicate. I'll work reverse a integer for proper output. ☺

Comment: I don't think that reversing the output will do any good-- it is a coincidence that in my example I ended up with `321`. The final distribution of digits depends on the initial distribution of digits, because the procedure starts with the lowest order digits, and removes duplicates, working towards the high order digits. You can sort the digits if you want, but that will be another tricky problem.

Comment: This doesn't produce the desired output given the sample input. And it fails for numbers that cannot be represented by an `unsigned long`. Turning a problem that's best described as string-based into convoluted integer math mayhem never ends well.

Comment: @IInspectable-- there was no sample input. OP stated, and reiterated in a comment to your answer, that input should be an integer: "I need to pass a input integer value, not integer array." OP further stated that no arrays should be used. Granted, the OPs original code snippet was confusing, since it included arrays. My code does produce correct results. You are correct that it did not handle negative input. That has been fixed, and a discussion of that issue added to my answer.

Comment: From the OP's question: *"I/P:43456 O/P:4356"* - This is sample input (*"I/P"*) with the expected output (*"O/P"*). Your proposed answer fails to meet this specification. Besides, your update didn't fix the bug, that your code does not work for numbers that cannot be represented by an `unsigned long`.

Comment: Ahh-- I see what you mean. It wasn't clear to me from the specification that the ordering was important. I took OPs comment: "I'll work reverse a integer for proper output" to mean that they wanted to put the digits in ascending order (the original code returned `321` given `12321`). Extrapolating from the sample input (which I just missed the first time) would mean that `12321` should return `123`. My above code returns `3456` given the sample input. This is probably what the "reverse a integer" comment was really directed at. I will see if I can modify my code to comply.

Comment: @IInspectable-- Sorry about the confusion. I have modified my code to remove duplicates in the correct order and updated the text of my answer. Thanks for bearing with me!

Comment: @Meena-- I have updated my answer to remove duplicates in the order that you specifed. Sorry about the misunderstanding.

Comment: It still fails for integers that cannot be represented by the data type you chose to represent them. Again, there is no need whatsoever to even store the "integer" as an integer data type. Use a string instead, and you have both a problem that's easier to solve, as well as a more generic solution (that doesn't violate the [zero one infinity rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zero_one_infinity_rule) either).

Answer (score 1):

This is a rough sketch:

For each integer in the input, traverse the input towards the beginning, and compare each integer to the current one. If there is a match, move on to the next input integer. If you reach the beginning, it isn't a duplicate, so print it.

```
void printRepeating(const int arr[], size_t size) {
    const int* begin = arr;
    const int* end = arr + size;
    if ( begin == end ) return;
    // First element cannot be a duplicate, so always print it
    std::cout << *begin;
    // Traverse input array
    const int* curr = begin;
    while ( ++curr < end ) {
        // Traverse back to find a duplicate
        const int* curr_rev = curr - 1;
        for ( ; curr_rev >= begin && *curr != *curr_rev; --curr_rev );
        if ( curr_rev < begin )
            // Reached the beginning, so it cannot be a duplicate
            std::cout << " " << *curr;
    }
}
```

And while I'm not sure, whether constructing a pointer to the element just before an array is undefined behavior, here is a slight variation, that traverses the input from front to back to find a duplicate. This is just the main loop - everything else like above:

```
    // Traverse input array
    const int* curr = begin;
    while ( ++curr < end ) {
        // Traverse again to find a duplicate
        const int* cmp = begin;
        for ( ; cmp < curr && *cmp != *curr; ++cmp );
        if ( cmp == curr )
            // Reached current integer, so it cannot be a duplicate
            std::cout << " " << *curr;
    }
```

Given this program:

```
int main() {
    const int arr[]{ 1, 2, 3, 1, 3, 6, 6 };
    printRepeating( arr, std::end( arr ) - std::begin( arr ) );
}
```

produces the following output:

> ```
> 1 2 3 6
> ```

Comment: I need to pass a input integer value, not integer array. If you don't mine can you rework for me..

Comment: @Meena: I probably could. But since you asked a different question, and I answered that different question, I don't see, why I should change this. If you need an answer to a another question, [ask another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) instead.

Answer (score 0):

For your example

> I/P:43456 O/P:4356

one way to think about this is that a digit is output only if it isn't also present in the more-significant part of the number. So we go through each digit from least- to most-significant. If the digit (`lastdig(num)`) is present in the more-significant part of the number (`butlastdig(num)`), we discard it, otherwise we keep it.

```
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>

inline unsigned lastdig(unsigned n) { return n%10; }
inline unsigned butlastdig(unsigned n) { return n/10; }
inline bool is_single_digit(unsigned n) { return n<10; }

bool is_in(unsigned digit, unsigned num)
{
    if (is_single_digit(num))
        return digit==num;
    else
        return (digit==lastdig(num)) || is_in(digit, butlastdig(num));
}

unsigned unique(unsigned num)
{
    unsigned last, butlast;

    if (is_single_digit(num))
        return num;
    last=lastdig(num);        
    butlast=unique(butlastdig(num));

    if (is_in(last, butlast))
        return butlast;
    else
        return butlast*10 + last;
}

main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int i=atoi(argv[1]);
    if (i < 0)
        printf("nonnegative numbers only\n");
    else
        printf("%u %u\n", i, unique(i));
}
```

Comment: Same issue as with the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40168237/1889329) provided by David Bowling. You are making the problem both more difficult to solve as well as limit the solution's applicability by using integer data types. Use a string instead and have a simpler, and more generic solution.

Comment: Can't use a C string, since that's an array and OP is constrained not to use arrays. I used arrays only in the user interface portion of the program, and avoided using them in the algorithmic portion.

Comment: The OP never claimed, that the **input** couldn't be stored as an array (their question does just that anyway). I read the question to mean: *"Don't use an array in the algorithm."* (probably to keep someone going for the obvious solution using `bool dupes[10];`). And I guess the goal of the interview question was `1` to verify, whether the candidate could easily identify a problem that has a straight forward recursive solution, and `2` whether they were then capable of transforming the tail recursion into an iterative algorithm.